# Error Boundaries catching error then showing error

Tags: reactjs

I've create an ErrorBoundry component which is wrapped around all child components of App. I've added a throw error function to one of the child components to test. When the component renders it seems the ErrorBoundry is catching the error but then the error appears after it. What am I doing wrong.

Here's my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/n0qjwjvrnm

Comment: I think you can't throw error in react component you may need redux or something else to show your error by state.

Comment: I found this example https://codepen.io/sgroff04/pen/dVbgJy which uses  throw new Error

Comment: I'm sorry I totally wrong this is new feature in react16 and codepen has exactly the same example as yours maybe sandbox will catch the error?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a feature of Code Sandbox? Have you tried running this code in a different environment?

Comment: No i've tried this inside a local build also and it's behaving the same way.

Comment: That's interesting I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this please take a look in the error overlay.

> This error overlay is powered by `react-error-overlay` used in
>   `create-react-app`.

I tested in my app and it show the correct behavior because I'm not using create-react-app so this is the feature powered by it.

This is not a bug. Cheers.